# Parsing multiple IDs from a URL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, hashtag

I'm building a sort-of Twitter clone, with (amongst others), models and Hashtag and Post, which have a `has_many: through:` relationship with each other.

Currently, visiting `/hashtags/pizza` will take you to a page that shows all posts with hashtag the hashtag *#pizza*. I want to add functionality so you can pass *multiple* hashtags in a URL and see the posts which contain *all* of those hashtags. For example, if you visited `/hashtags/pizza/pasta` (or `hashtags/?pizza&pasta'` or whatever's easiest to implement) you'd be shown a page containing all Posts which have BOTH the hashtag *#pizza* and the hashtag *#pasta*.

How would I do this? I have no idea where to begin.

For the record, my imagined code in the controller would be something like this. Feel free to poke holes in it:

```
1  def show
2    requested_hashtags = ??????? # an array of hashtags e.g. ["music", "guitar"]
3    hashtag1 = Hashtag.find_by_name(requested_hashtags[0]) # in this case r_h[0] = music
4    hashtag2 = Hashtag.find_by_name(requested_hashtags[1]) # and r_h[1] = guitar
5    @posts = hashtag1.posts & hashtag2.posts
6  end
```

Then in my view I'd just iterate over `@posts`. (The above example is dumbed down in that it assumes there's always exactly two hashtags requested but the principle is the same.)

So my question is, how do I complete line **2** of the code snippet above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can treat the url like any other string, so you could create a url like:

```
hashtags/?tags=pizza,pasta
```

And then in your controller (line 2):

```
requested_hashtags = params[:tags].split(",")
```

Another more commonly used approach in Rails is:

```
hashtags/?tags[]=pizza&tags[]=pasta
```

and then in your controller:

```
 requested_hashtags = params[:tags]
```

This second way is a pretty standard Rails convention.

Comment: So what would I put in `config/routes.rb` to match (say) `hashtags/?tags[]=pizza&tags[]=pasta` to the right controller? Would I use a regex? How?

Thanks though!

Comment: You can just have a route to your show action. Anything that comes after the question mark doesn't need to be specified in the routes file.